# Detect if a month is missing and insert them automatically with a select statement (MSSQL)

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, recursive-query

I am trying to write a select statement which detects if a month is not existent and automatically inserts that month with a value 0. It should insert all missing months from the first entry to the last entry.

Example:
My table looks like this:

[image]

After the statement it should look like this:

[image]

Comment: Create a calendar table (yes, it's a common concept) with all dates, then left join on it. Or create a numbers table to dynamically create the calendar dates you're interested in, and left join on that.  Either tend to be simpler and more efficient that a CTE used to fill in the gaps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a recursive `CTE` to get all the years in the table (and the missing ones if any) and another one to get all the month numbers 1-12.
A `CROSS` join of these CTEs will be joined with a `LEFT` join to the table and finally filtered so that rows prior to the first year/month and later of the last year/month are left out:

```
WITH
  limits AS (
    SELECT MIN(year) min_year, -- min year in the table
           MAX(year) max_year, -- max year in the table
           MIN(DATEFROMPARTS(year, monthnum, 1)) min_date, -- min date in the table 
           MAX(DATEFROMPARTS(year, monthnum, 1)) max_date  -- max date in the table
    FROM tablename
   ),
  years(year) AS ( -- recursive CTE to get all the years of the table (and the missing ones if any)
    SELECT min_year FROM limits
    UNION ALL
    SELECT year + 1 
    FROM years
    WHERE year < (SELECT max_year FROM limits)
  ),  
  months(monthnum) AS ( -- recursive CTE to get all the month numbers 1-12
    SELECT 1 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT monthnum + 1
    FROM months
    WHERE monthnum < 12
  )
SELECT y.year, m.monthnum,
       DATENAME(MONTH, DATEFROMPARTS(y.year, m.monthnum, 1)) month,
       COALESCE(value, 0) value
FROM months m CROSS JOIN years y
LEFT JOIN tablename t 
ON t.year = y.year AND t.monthnum = m.monthnum
WHERE DATEFROMPARTS(y.year, m.monthnum, 1) 
      BETWEEN (SELECT min_date FROM limits) AND (SELECT max_date FROM limits)
ORDER BY y.year, m.monthnum
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=460afe08163a9592d306e8ce47d2b04a).

Answer (score 0):

You should not be storing date components in two separate columns; instead, you should have just one column, with a proper `date`-like datatype.

One approach is to use a recursive query to generate all starts of month between the earliest and latest date in the table, then brin the table with a `left join`.

In SQL Server:

```
with cte as (
    select min(datefromparts(year, monthnum, 1)) as dt,
        max(datefromparts(year, monthnum, 1)) as dt_max
    from mytable
    union all
    select dateadd(month, 1, dt) 
    from cte
    where dt < dt_max
)
select c.dt, coalesce(t.value, 0) as value
from cte c
left join mytable t on datefromparts(t.year, t.month, 1) = c.dt
```

If your data spreads over more that 100 months, you need to add `option(maxrecursion 0)` at the end of the query.

You can extract the date components in the final `select` if you like:

```
select 
    year(c.dt) as yr, 
    month(c.dt) as monthnum, 
    datename(month, c.dt) as monthname,
    coalesce(t.value, 0) as value
from ...
```